# Do C++ compilers automatically zero initialize dynamic arrays declared in local functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, initialization

I have read that **global** arrays are initialized to 0 by default. I tried experimenting with local arrays and declared one in the main function.

```
    int main()
    {
        int* x = new int[10];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            cout<<x[i]<<" ";
        }
         return 0;
     }
```

I got the output as: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Are local arrays always initialized to 0? I am using CodeBlocks GCC if its of any help.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: No, not for `int`.  The elements will get default initialized which for `int` means no initialization.  What you are seeing is the compiler being "helpful" by zeroing the memory.  debug builds do this to help find bugs in code.

Comment: `int* x = new int[10];` -> no initialization `int* x = new int[10]();` -> value-initialization

Comment: Only when you specify an empty initializer. Like `()` or `{}`, e.g. `new int[10]{}`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you. Is there a way to definitively know whether a compiler will auto-initialize arrays?

Comment: There are situations where you will know what the value will be, and those are detailed in the duplicate link.